# How to sort multiples dictionnaries in an array in python?

Tags: python

Good evening,

I'd like to sort my dictionnaries only in function of one parameter. My dictionnaries are in an array like that

```
[{'name': 'Silopp', 'size': 14924, 'distanceToStar': 90248452, 'mass': 194532}, {'name': 'Astrion', 'size': 152000, 'distanceToStar': 149302, 'mass': 2194}, {'name': 'Valenus', 'size': 290450, 'distanceToStar': 20948593455, 'mass': 195293}]
```

and I would like to sort it in function of the distance to the star, using the increasing order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remember that asking on SO isn't a substitute for doing your own research.

Comment: the way we can do it is like:  res = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: x['distanceToStar'])